# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when I use UITabBarController but have to use it nonetheless

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I started my iOS app template using master-detail application and core data checkbox being on, and went to storyboard and embedded in tabbar controller to navigation controller, which was there when I created the app, and ran the simulator, I got an error: `unrecognized selector to instance 0x10972f880`.

Also, when I created a new class named `rootTabBarController` inherited from `UITabBarController` and went back to storyboard and set its tabbar controller's class at `rootTabBarController`, the class name completion functionality doesn't work there (which has worked almost always so far in my Xcode).

So I think I'm missing something. And I'd also like to know why Xcode doesn't even tell me about the line number of the error - it is basically impossible to solve the error without knowing where it happened, which I think almost any languages (at least I've ever experienced, which includes Python, Go, or JavaScript) kindly teach me in general. Or there's no way to know about it?

I know even if I start single-view application or tabbar application I can still use Core Data functionality if I add its framework and write every code necessary. I just want to know whether it is feasible to use core data at default and still use tabbar controller as root and navigation controller as leaf and use core data in table view of the navigation controller instead of adding core data framework and writing its code all over the place.

Or do I have to start single-view application and add core data and write its code from scratch if I want to use tabbar controller at root instead of navigation controller?

Comment: You are absolutely correct in assuming that you're missing a stack trace that will tell you where the error occurred. [Add a break on all exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) run again, and post the stack if you still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what I should select is empty application with core data being checked on, and add tabbar and navigation controllers instead of adding core data later and writing lots of its code in `AppDelegate.m` file, from [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0N1pe5pJ2k).

Here's the procedure to follow:

1. start in empty application and add storyboard
2. delete code within `application: didFinishLaunchingOptions:` method.
3. add tabbar controller, navigation controller, etc.. to storyboard and done.

I've not tried using Core Data functionality yet, which is the next thing that I have to do. However, I can successfully build and run the application so far. As to the elusive error that I initially got, I don't know how to solve it. If I were to get to know the answer I would edit this post.